# Trouble reading mnist with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, mnist

So apparently the Yann LeCun's website is down so the following lines for reading mnist with tensorflow don't seem to be working :

```
FROM tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist IMPORT input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot = true)
```

Any ideas how can i read the mnist without using these above lines?

Comment: your email? I can send a copy for you

Comment: smooth3r93@gmail.com
Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: @Jie.Zhou smooth3r93@gmail.com Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: You can find an already decoded version of the MNIST dataset here: http://mnist-decoded.000webhostapp.com/

Answer (score 3):

You can access the website here: https://web.archive.org/web/20160117040036/http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/ - download the data, and read it in from a local copy...

**Edit**
[Here](https://github.com/ischlag/tensorflow-input-pipelines/blob/master/datasets/mnist.py) is a code example for reading a local mnist dataset

Comment: @Priyank I've edited the link to the source of the old article. There are many newer tutorials out there - this example doesn't seem to be up to date anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the dataset individually and put it in the directory you created.Then the code can run normally.
http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/

Comment: i have downloaded the dataset,how can i read  it in my code now?

Comment: 'FROM tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist IMPORT input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot = true)'      it works well but you should put the dir MNIST_data/ in your current project.

Comment: Will it be the same if I am using R programming ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys i fixed my problem,my mistake was that i was extracting the files(to the \MNIST_data directory) from the .gz files where i should have left them as they were unextracted instead.Thanks for the help.