# Tensorflow cannot load mnist

Tags: tensorflow, mnist

I downloaded a copy of mnist data from a random website because the official website was down.
Which directory can I put the mnist file for tensorflow's input_data method to pick it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42927841/trouble-reading-mnist-with-tensorflow) help you.

Another way to use MNIST dataset: some Frameworks like Tensorflow and Keras has this dataset. So you can use this:

```
# Import MNIST
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

# Load data
X_train = mnist.train.images
Y_train = mnist.train.labels
X_test = mnist.test.images
Y_test = mnist.test.labels
```

The sample example in [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimators/cnn):
In Keras also its same and you can import and use. Both Frameworks download it first and then just need to import.